# Upadating of packages after installation of new program

Tags: updates

Is the command `apt-get update`  necessary after every new package installation and for broken packages?

Since I'm new to this OS I have to search commands for packages and every  solution contains this part. Why is it so necessary?

Answer (score 1):

You need the command `apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get update` when you add, remove or change entries in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` or in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

from `man apt-get`:

```
update
    update is used to resynchronize the package index files from their sources.
    The indexes of available packages are fetched from the location(s) specified in
    /etc/apt/sources.list. For example, when using a Debian  archive, this command
    retrieves and scans the Packages.gz files, so that information about new and
    updated packages is available. An update should always be performed before an
    upgrade or dist-upgrade. Please be aware that the overall progress meter will
    be incorrect as the size of the package files cannot be known in advance.
```

And I quote [@Tom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624086/upadating-of-packages-after-installation-of-new-program/624088?noredirect=1#comment884352_624088)

> Routinely run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to get bugfixes and such though.

Comment: So what does this mean? Does it need to be done before / after installation?

Comment: You do not need the command, if you only install software.

Comment: @MnPr4UB it depends.  You need to do `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` routinely after installation to get bugfixes, new versions, etc.  However, the most often case of needing to run `apt-get update` is after adding a new source to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.  The packaging system has no idea what packages are available in the new source location until you run it.   You then typically run an `install` command to install from that new source, and `sudo apt-get update` later to get updates from that source, or to 'forget' the source if you removed it.

Comment: @MnPr4UB However, as A.B. said, if you are only installing software you don't typically need the command every time.  Routinely run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` to get bugfixes and such though.

Comment: Ahh, so after a ppa add  remove. :) I see